# Use a string to find some cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to generate a table with a new column `CNUM` which will be fill by the digit ID of some city (city in column `VILLE`).

Sometimes, more than one city could have the same name. That's why, I would like to have multiple dropbox for each city in the `CNUM` olumn.

My table is on sheet `Liste candidats`. The table where I have the correspondance between City name and City ID is on sheet `Dropbox` and the place where I build all the stuff I need for future dropbox list is on `Sheets2`.

I'm stuck with my following code, it's working if I use `city name`: (after autoselect the table)

```
Dim I As Integer

'Je fais une [Loop] allant de la ligne 1 jusqu'a l'avant derniere ligne de la sélection précédente
For I = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
    Dim rFoundAddress As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim VILLA As String
            
    VILLA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Liste candidats").Range("MonTab[VILLE]")(I)
    
    x = 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dropdown").Columns(2)
        Set rFoundAddress = .Find(VILLA & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rFoundAddress Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAddress = rFoundAddress.Address
            Do
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 1 + (I - 1) * 3) = .Cells(rFoundAddress.Row, 1 - 1)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 2 + (I - 1) * 3) = .Cells(rFoundAddress.Row, 1)
                x = x + 1
                Set rFoundAddress = .FindNext(rFoundAddress)
            Loop While Not rFoundAddress Is Nothing And _
                rFoundAddress.Address <> sFirstAddress
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Now, I would like to use the string `VILLA` and add something to add more results :
(result with and without : accent, L', Les, -, etc..)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sorry but that makes no sense to me. Could you attach a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find a solution with this code:

Set rFoundAddress = .Find(VILLA & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

Is it a way to have a chance to get the same result, no matter of "é/è/e/à/l'/-/ê/ç" présent or not in the city name ????

Thanks

Comment: Would not cover all possibilities, but `Find` allows wild cards. So you could look for "St. Rémy" via "St. R?my" for instance and check all possible results (whether hypothetically there exists also a city named Ramy or Rámy or Romy etc). - Btw don't ask new questions here, this is reserved for answers.

Comment: Sorry... since I had found an answer, I took the opportunity to answer and ask a question at the same time.
Thanks for your help but now, since I can use "VILLA" for each row, I would like to use it in Find. 
Your idea is great but I dont think I can apply it to solve my problem.

Comment: ooh I've just understood. I will try to creat a function that replace all special character by "?" in each VILLA !